# Python/Django/Q search, How to find B field info. by searching A field info

Tags: python, django, post

Most examples are in the form of finding A in data A to Z.

A DB table does not have a single field from A to Z. When a DB table has several fields together, I want to know the field I'm looking for as a field value and I want to figure out another value with that field value.

For example, searching for a specific name in a DB that contains information from all the students will determine the age.

from Python, Django DB

My data consists of 3 rows:

```
{title:'1', price:'20'}
{title:'2', price:'30'}
{title:'1', price:'10'}
```

I want to find title `'1'` and then return price fileds

**Expexted Output:**

```
{title:'1', price:'20'}
{title:'1', price:'10'}
```

**Views.py:**

```
@csrf_exempt
def searching(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        parameter = request.POST.get('title')
        searchResult = NaverData.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=parameter)).distinct()
        ouput = searchResult
        return HttpResponse(ouput)
    else:
        #GET request
        return HttpResponse('GET REQUEST')
```

Comment: I don't get what's the problem, Once you filter the queryset, it will return entries with that filter condition and after that you can access the result queryset entry prices?!

Comment: Your DB data is in json (string) or the class has attribute "title: int" and "price: int"
if the stored data is json, then it will kinda hard to do the filter (query on text).

Comment: Suppose A and 2 are in the same table. If I find A, I want information 2 about A.
Now my code is find A and then ouput is A.

Comment: Most examples are in the form of finding A in data A to Z.

A DB table does not have a single field from A to Z. When a DB table has several fields together, I want to know the field I'm looking for as a field value and I want to figure out another value with that field value.

For example, searching for a specific name in a DB that contains information from all the students will determine the age.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check this

```
   searchresult= NaverData.objects.values("prize").filter(title__exact=parameter)
```

Comment: oh! thank you!! it works! 
I do not know django for the first time, so it is hard to find. Great help!

Comment: then approve it

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
searchResult = NaverData.objects.all().filter(title=parameter)
```